# Keep Refreshed Table after Refresh Button is Clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax

I have a mock website that I'm creating just for practice. I'm working with `AJAX`, loader icons, and file uploads. For this, I have a `File Upload`, an `ASP Button` to load the file, and `HTML Button` to refresh the table with AJAX, and a table whose HTML is always built using a `StringBuilder`.

Here's what I need to happen; right now I'm just setting up my button events. The upload file WILL send a `Postback` due to a file being uploaded (eventually) but the refresh button will NOT. The page loads the table BEFORE data is added to the database. Then that table is replaced by a new table that displays new data after the refresh button is clicked and new data has been entered. The upload button should not reload the table. The issue I have right now is that I can click the upload after manually adding data and the table remains the same. The refresh shows that data. However, when I hit the upload button AGAIN, the table returns to it's original set of data, before I manually added stuff. Why? I changed the div's html to contain the new table, so why is it going back to the old?

Not sure if I explained this well enough but... there ya go. If anyone can help, that would be great~ I'd love to increase my knowledge and skill-set whenever possible. :)

Here is an image (Please note that I am NOT a web designer and that the overall design is simple and well... just plain bad):
[image: MockSite]

Here is a piece of the back-end .cs code. This is just the Page_Load event, it prevents the table from reloading on a postback which is called from the `Upload Button`. "GetData()" is just the method that creates the table using a `StringBuilder` which is then injected into a div with the help of an asp:Literal. I don't see it necessary to post the "GetData()" method but will if requested.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ShowData.Text = GetData();
    }
}
```

Here is the script portion that uses AJAX to refresh the table by using .get() which refers to an .ashx file that produces the same table as "GetData()". The code in the .ashx is also unnecessary but will post if requested.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#refresh").click(function (event) {
                    $.get("helpers/TableLoad.ashx", function (data) {
                        $("#tableHolder").html(data);
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: How are you preventing cached AJAX requests? If you're not, then that explains why the table doesn't update.

Comment: What code do you want to see exactly? The Script? Back-end C#? Or both? And not sure I understand what you mean by cached AJAX request. AJAX is new to me, hence this practice site, so I don't know much about it. I'm trying though~ If you have any helpful sites, I'd appreciate it. :) By the way, thank you guys for replying so quickly.